# How to check whether an object is empty in a span?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have some objects in my angularjs controller.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("noteCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.draft = {};
    $scope.notes = [];
    $scope.note = {};

$scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.notes.push($scope.note);
    $scope.note = {};
}; 

    $scope.save = function() {
        if ($scope.button == "Save") {
            $scope.draft = angular.copy($scope.note);
        } else {
            $scope.note = $scope.draft;
        }
    }; 

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $scope.note = {};
    }
});
```

I need to check whether the draft object is empty, and output the save successfully information.

```
<span data-ng-hide="draft == {}" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```

I have also tried:

```
<span data-ng-hide="draft.length == -1" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```

or

```
<span data-ng-hide="draft == ''" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```

But all of them are failed.

Comment: Where are the arrays?

Comment: What is `$scope.note`?

Comment: $scope.note is to store data from a form

Comment: `$scope.draft` and `$scope.draft` are object, not array. Do you want convert it to array?

Comment: if i am not wrong, `$scope.note=[]` is the correct array declaration and not `$scope.note={}`

Comment: I just updated my question, I have an array to store the objects. And I still want to know how to test the object is empty or not

Comment: If `draft` has some property you may check that e.g. `ng-hide="draft.id"`, otherwise add field to your `$scope` that will tell if draft is new object. `==` in JS just compares references so when you compare with `{}` you always get false, objects doesn't have `length` so it cannot work to and without overriding `toString` `obj.toString()` will return something like `[object Object]`

Comment: Object.keys(draft).length > 1

Answer (score 2):

Add function `isEmptyObject` in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("noteCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.draft = {};
  $scope.note = {};
  $scope.notes = [];

  $scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.button == "Save") {
      $scope.draft = angular.copy($scope.note);
    } else {
      $scope.note = $scope.draft;
    }
  }; 

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.note = {};
  }

  $scope.isEmptyObject = function (obj) {
    for (var i in obj) if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) return false;
    return true;
  };

});
```

Or you can use this function:

```
  $scope.isEmptyObject = function (obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<span data-ng-hide="isEmptyObject(draft)" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please initialize null instead of empty object

```
$scope.draft = null;
```

And html should be

```
<span data-ng-hide="!draft" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chek the condition inline in your span.

HTML:

```
<span data-ng-hide="Object.keys(draft).length === 0" style="color:green">Your note has been saved.</span>
```